# Assigning elements of a python list to a string

Tags: python, string, list, variable-assignment

How do I pass an element of a list to a string?

```
str i = categories[0]
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to code in Python, at this point you probably would bennefit from pausing your coding, and read a tutorial on the language. To start, there is no type declaration or variable declarations in the language.

Comment: I get the impression that you haven't even seen a single line of Python, much less tried to learn any.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly; just in case you were trying to declare "i" as a string...python is a weakly typed language which means you do not need to declare variable types. Instead of writing "int i = 5" you would just write "i = 5"

if categories is a list of strings do the following:

```
categories = ["CategoryA", "CategoryB", "CategoryC"]

i = categories[0]
```

if categories is not a list of strings but you want to convert the value of one of the index's of categories to a string do the following:

```
categories = [128, 240, 380]
i = str(categories[0])
```

if you ever need to convert it back to an int (or possibly convert it to a float) you can use

```
int(i)
```

or

```
float(i)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I just realized that there was something else in my code that was interfering.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = categories[0]
```

did you actually try anything??

Answer (score 0):

e.g.

names = ['Bob', 'Steve', 'Matt']

for i in names:
    print('Hi, %s nice to meet you' % i)